# How to implement logical operator in bash using C?

Tags: c, bash, gnu, logical-operators

I am new to C programming. I am trying to write a simple command line interpreter with logical operator. It works like this:

```
command1 ; command2 || command3 && command4
if ; second command will be executed after first command
if || second command only be executed if first command failed
if && second command will only be executed if first one succeeded
```

For example:

```
echo one ; echo one || echo two && echo four
```

the output should look like this:

> one
>
> one
>
> four

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

```
int command_execute(void){
int i;
int next = 0;
int previous = 0;
while(moperator >= 0){ //moperator recorded the numbers of logical operators
    if(execute(words[next], next)== 0){ //words stored the tokenize string 
        moperator--;                    
        for(i = previous; i < nwds; i++){
            if(!strcmp(cwords[i], ";")){ //cwrods is a copy of words  
                previous = i;
                next = i + 1;
                moperator--;
                break;
            }else if(!strcmp(cwords[i], "||")){
                continue;
            }else if(!strcmp(cwords[i], "&&")){
                moperator--;
                previous = i;
                next = i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }else{
        for(i = previous; i < nwds; i++){
            if(!strcmp(cwords[i], ";")){
                previous = i;
                next = i + 1;
                break;
            }else if(!strcmp(cwords[i], "||")){
                previous = i;
                next = i + 1;
                break;
            }else if(!strcmp(cwords[i], "&&")){
                    continue;
                }
        }    
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the method I wrote to call to execute the command. The input had been tokenized by eliminating the whitespace.

Comment: why couldn't you use just add this to your question insteading of putting it as an answer?